# How can you get filepicker.stat() to return dimensions for a rotated image?

Tags: image-processing, filepicker.io, filepicker

We are grabbing and storing image metadata in the success callback from a `filepicker.pickAndStore()`. Right now we are getting the dimensions using `filepicker.stat()`:

```
// file is an object returned from the success callback
filepicker.stat(file, { width: true, height: true }, function(metadata) {
  // our app code
});
```

We'd like to have the width and height return the dimensions for the rotated image (using `rotate=exif`). What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Did you get any solution by any chance?